# Sybase Batch insert deadlock

Tags: database, exception, deadlock, sybase, sap-ase

I am using ASE 15.0.3 and have issues with a java process that every now and than throws an Exception when trying to perform a batch insert (via sql query and not stored procedure) in a table. Below is the exception :
`JZ0BE: BatchUpdateException: Error occurred while executing batch statement: Your server command (family id #0, process id #61) encountered a deadlock situation. Please re-run your command.`

The table in which it is trying to insert has many columns but only one (non-clustered) index on an id (int identity) column.

Other (concurrent) processes that interact with this table can perform one of 2 things :

```
1) Select data from the table (transaction based)

2) Delete data from the table (transaction based, and first requiring an 
exclusive table lock with wait 20 sec).
```

The hunch is that the deadlock comes from the index pages. Cannot convert the locking mechanism to datapages or datarows since the table contains many large variable chars columns, that all add up to more than `8191` bytes and it displays : ... `exceeds limit of 8191 bytes for column-offset of variable-length columns in DOL tables. Future inserts to this table may fail.`

Any ideas on how this situation can be avoided ? (other than removing the index from the table).

Thanks

Comment: You could turn on deadlock logging to the errorlog and find out exactly what deadlocked.  MDA tables can do the same, but I know it's possible to find useful info from the errorlog.

Would it be the SELECT as the other side?  Because an exclusive table lock ought not to participate in a deadlock.

But if so I can see that DOL is desirable, but you're stuck there.

Can you trap the error and resubmit?  It sounds like you've already decided against that.

Comment: when i first checked the logs... there was nothing, so logging must have been turned off. Since then, the deadlock did not occur, i'll take a look at the log the next time it occurs. It appears rarely, but it causes a lot of discomfort when it does.

Comment: would it be very hard to add a check of the error message and automatic resub?

Comment: Am having a similar problem now; trying to play with some settings like commit level; but even if it works, being unable to point a definite finger at the problem is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

At first - do you have a triggers on the table? If yes - check all tables at the trigger.
Which lock schema do you use for this table? If it's a allpages lock - try it change to datapage/datarow.
Regarding exception of row size limit - i think you should investigate a possibility of the splitting table or changing table structure...